# Did Henri III of France sleep with men? Did he not sleep with women?

Tags: historiography, historical-accuracy

[Henry III of France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_III_of_France) was the last of the Valois line. He became king illegally (according to some sources). He produced no children. He had "[Les Mignons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mignons)" a group of very close friends he pampered and showered with favors: some say they were more than just friends.

He has been described as effeminate by historians and novelists alike. He had an aversion to women. He never entered his wife's bedroom. In his trilogy in which Henri figures as one of the major characters, Alexandre Dumas, Pere all but refers to him as homosexual.

[image]

Now suddenly historians reverse their opinion on him. According to them he had a stormy affair in Poland with a woman he loved. He also loved his wife with whom he had sexual intercourse practically every night. The canard about him being gay was concocted by his slanderers.

Why the sudden change?

Comment: Can You deliver these 'new' sources (historians that present reverse opinion)?

Comment: (1) "gay" is not binary; it is perfectly possible that both statements are true. (2) Who cares? (3) sources.  If you don't provide sources then discussion of the quality of their research and conclusions are pure speculation.

Comment: What historians? A link/reference or two would be quite helpful.

Comment: "He was the last of the Valois line" and "He produced no children" are saying the same thing, and they are irrelevant because it is both possible to be straight and childless, and to be gay and have children. "He became king illegally" seems irrelevant. *He allegedly had friends that were more than friends* also could be true of a king who messed around but wasn't necessarily gay. "He has been described as effeminate" is irrelevant because gender expression and sexual orientation are two different things.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - Do I care if someone I meet socially today is gay? Not really. Do I care if a historical figure was? Most certainly yes. In a culture that didn't accept that at all, it makes a huge difference in a person's mentality and motivations, which is something I'm very interested in where a historical figure is concerned.

Comment: As the terminological issue has been resolved, and the author of a reasonable question deserves a useful answer, I've deleted my response. The end of henrigate 2015.

Comment: How is this question going to be answerable? What would be taken as an authoritative source, given that all the interested partied died centuries ago and clearly left no direct testimony?

Comment: @called2voyage: The statements "He was the last of the Valois line" and "He produced no children" are only the same when and if Henry both had no siblings and there were no cadet branches of the Valois line extant at his death. That is by no means a given unless explicitly stated, particularly for a long-lived line such as the Valois.

Comment: And one could well produce children and still be the last of the line if the children die without issue before the king dies.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I didn't mean they were equivalent statements, just that the implication here is the same.

Comment: This is a potentially interesting question. It's unfortunate that you didn't pencil in your sources as requested in the comments for years on end in spite of showing up on the site from time to time. Perhaps you found the answer in the meanwhile?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: I do mention some sources. Read the Dumas trilogy: it's very entertaining.